# Remote Transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp, transactions, msdtc

How would I "join" two transactional components across a network call?

[Note: It's safe to assume both sides are using C#.]

Details: 
Say, we have two servers, A and B. A process on A (let's say X) communicates with a service Y on B over TCP. This communication does not use WCF, and is simple bytes passed over TCP. X also deals with a SQL Server, M. Y deals with a SQL Server N.
What I want to do:

1. Client starts a call in X inside a TransactionScope.
2. It deals with SQL Server M and makes a call over TCP out to Y.
3. Y does something with SQL Server Y.

I would like all of this to honour the TransactionScope the initial client call is made in. In other words, a failure on either side should rollback both sides.

How do I make Y engage in the transaction started in X? I'm aware that MS DTC would need to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are attempting to create a "distributed transaction" in which two or more tables are updated in a single transactions while these tables happened to be defined in different databases that are run on different SQL Server servers. A "two-phase commit" process is used to coordinate between the two servers so that the update is either successful on each server or is rolled back on each server if any one server encounters a problem.

This Microsoft SQL Server page on "[Transact-SQL Distributed Transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)" covers how to do this. One requirement is that the two SQL Server servers will need to have a "Linked Server" association defined between them. This may need to be defined by a systems or database administrator due to security ramifications. (Look in the SQL Server Management Studio under "Server Objects" for the "Linked Server" associations defined by the SQL Server server that you are currently connected to.)

However, it appears that it is preferred to manage custom distributed transactions in which database updates are performed on two different servers. That is a lot more work. In effect, this is like emulating a DTC-like distributed transactions without using DTC. The communications needed between your two servers are crtical and you'll also need to deal with timeout conditions in case one server does not respond to an action request.

An example of this processing sequence is ...

1) Client starts a call in X inside a TransactionScope.

2) A transaction is started on Server M for this call.

3) Server M's transaction updates are made, but NOT comitted.

4) Server M communicates with Server Y to do its updates for the X TransactionScope.

5) Server Y starts its own transaction, does its updates, commits the updates and returns a success / error status back to Server M

6) Server M then commits its updates if the Server Y updates were successful; if not, then Server M does a rollback of its pending updates.

Server M will also need to handle timeouts on the Server Y request if the expected success / error status is not returned within a predetermined amount of time.

Another difficult situation is how to undo the Server Y updates if the final commit of the Server M transaction generates an error. For this situation you'll need to send an "undo" request to Server Y to somehow undo an update that had already been committed. (A manual correction on Server Y may be an acceptable option for this error condition.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I'm not looking to carry out a distributed transaction across two SQL Server instances. I'm looking to support distributed transactions with my own code. For example, say my library provides a function to call out to a web service (non-DTC, external). And the external service has another function to reverse the changes. I would like clients of my lib to be able to use my library inside a transaction block, so that in case of rollback, I can make the compensating call. i.e. I want to enlist my own code with the DTC, not use two resources that support DTC,